Error de array en JSON
Buen día.
Estoy realizando un mapa de la API de google, pero tengo un archivo que realiza las consultas de mysql llamado controlador donde me permite realizarlas en query, y otro llamado function donde se desarrolla el mapa y figuras a partir de la función de controlador. Anteriormente esto estaba en xml pero deseo emigrar la información a JSON. En cuestión de reverse es porque tengo figuras dentro de una figura y necesito que se pinten de manera individual y no agrupadas por la figura mas grande.
Sin embargo me esta generando un problema con mi array.
FUNCIÓN EN functions
function dibujarUT(datosUT){ //Agujeros de UTs en selecciona una UT

  const icon = {
        url: "imagenes/punto.png",
        scaledSize: new google.maps.Size(40, 40), // scaled size
        origin: new google.maps.Point(0,0), // origin
        anchor: new google.maps.Point(0, 0) // anchor
    };
            /*Inicia propiedades del mapa*/
            bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
            const mapOptions = {
              center: { lat: 19.432777, lng: -99.133217 },
              // Rotaciín inicial
              // heading: 180,
              // tilt: 60,
              // Ésto permite la inclinación y la vista 3D
              mapId: "90f87356969d889c",
              zoom: 20,
              //mapTypeId: "terrain"
            };

            map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map2'), mapOptions);


            const buttons = [
            ["Rotar a la izquierda", "rotate", 20, google.maps.ControlPosition.LEFT_CENTER],
            ["Rotar a la derecha", "rotate", -20, google.maps.ControlPosition.RIGHT_CENTER],
            ["Inclinar hacia abajo", "tilt", 20, google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_CENTER],
            ["Inclinar hacia arriba", "tilt", -20, google.maps.ControlPosition.BOTTOM_CENTER],
            ];

            buttons.forEach(([text, mode, amount, position]) => {
            const controlDiv = document.createElement("div");
            const controlUI = document.createElement("button");

            controlUI.classList.add("ui-button");
            controlUI.innerText = `${text}`;
            controlUI.addEventListener("click", () => {
              adjustMap(mode, amount);
            });
            controlDiv.appendChild(controlUI);
            map.controls[position].push(controlDiv);
            });

            const adjustMap = function (mode, amount) {
              switch (mode) {
                case "tilt":
                  map.setTilt(map.getTilt() + amount);
                  break;
                case "rotate":
                  map.setHeading(map.getHeading() + amount);
                  break;
                default:
                  break;
              }
            };
    
            
           
            let datos = JSON.parse(datosUT.responseText);
            var id, entidad, claveDT, nombreDT, dttoL_2023, claveUT, nombreUT, seccC, seccP, tipoUT, poblacion, ln, color;
            let contentString = ""; 

            

                    id = datos[0].id;
                    entidad =datos[0].entidad;
                    claveDT = datos[0].claveDT;
                    nombreDT = datos[0].nombreDT;
                    dttoL_2023 =datos[0].dttoL_2023;
                    claveUT = datos[0].claveUT;
                    nombreUT = datos[0].nombreUT;
                    seccC =datos[0].seccC;
                    seccP = datos[0].seccP;
                    tipoUT = datos[0].tipoUT;
                    poblacion =datos[0].poblacion;
                    ln = datos[0].ln;
                    color = datos[0].color;
                    poligonoUT = datos[0].geom.substring(15, datos[0].geom.length-3);
             

            // Texto del marcador
            contentString =
            '<div id="content">'+
              '<div id="siteNotice">' +
              '</div>' +
              ' <h6 id="firstHeading" class="firstHeading">'+nombreUT+'</h6>' +
              '<div id="bodyContent">' +
                '<table id = "tablamapa" border="1" align="center">'+
                  '<tr>' +
                    '<td>Entidad</td>' +
                    '<td>' + entidad + '</td>' +
                  '</tr>'+
                  '<tr>' +
                    '<td>Cve. Demarcación Territorial</td>' +
                    '<td>' + claveDT + '</td>' +
                  '</tr>'+
                  '<tr>' +
                    '<td>Demarcación Territorial</td>' +
                    '<td>' + nombreDT + '</td>' +
                  '</tr>'+
                  // '<tr>' +
                  //   '<td>Distrito Local.</td>' +
                  //   '<td>' + dttoL + '</td>' +
                  // '</tr>'+
                  '<tr>' +
                    '<td>Distrito Local</td>' +
                    '<td>' + dttoL_2023 + '</td>' +
                  '</tr>'+
                  '<tr>' +
                    '<td>Cve. Unidad Territorial</td>' +
                    '<td>' + claveUT + '</td>' +
                  '</tr>'+
                  '<tr>' +
                    '<td>Unidad Territorial</td>' +
                    '<td>' + nombreUT + '</td>' +
                  '</tr>'+
                  // '<tr>' +
                  //   '<td>Tipo UT</td>' +
                  //   '<td>' + tipoUT + '</td>' +
                  // '</tr>'+
                  '<tr>' +
                    '<td>Secciones Completas</td>' +
                    '<td id = "pobInegi">' + seccC+ '</td>' +
                  '</tr>'+
                  '<tr>' +
                    '<td>Secciones Parciales</td>' +
                    '<td>' + seccP + '</td>' +
                  '</tr>'+
                  '<tr>' +
                    '<td>Pob_x_UT_ECEG2020</td>' +
                    '<td>' + poblacion + '</td>' +
                  '</tr>'+
                  '<tr>' +
                    '<td>LN_30Junio2024</td>' +
                    '<td>' + ln + '</td>' +
                  '</tr>'+
                '</table>'+        
              '</div>' +
            '</div>';
            ;
    /* Configuración del poligono*/
  poligono = "";
  //Alvaro obregon
  if(claveUT == "10-200"){ //poligono grande
    poligono = new google.maps.Polygon({ 
    map: map,
    paths:[
          parsear(latlng),
          //Poligono interior dibujado en dirección opuesta al poligono expetrior
          parsearIndi(obtenerpoligono("10-244").split("\n")).reverse(),
          ],
    strokeColor: "#FFFFFF",// Color de linea
    strokeOpacity: 0.5, //opacidad de la linea
    strokeWeight: 3, //grosor de la linea
    fillColor: obtenerColor(color), // Color de relleno
    fillOpacity: 0.5, // opacidad del relleno
    id: claveUT,
    });
  }
  else if(claveUT == "10-105"){
    poligono = new google.maps.Polygon({ 
    map: map,
    paths:[
          parsear(latlng),
          //Poligono interior dibujado en dirección opuesta al poligono expetrior
          parsearIndi(obtenerpoligono("10-206").split("\n")).reverse(),
          ],
    strokeColor: "#FFFFFF",// Color de linea
    strokeOpacity: 0.5, //opacidad de la linea
    strokeWeight: 3, //grosor de la linea
    fillColor: obtenerColor(color), // Color de relleno
    fillOpacity: 0.5, // opacidad del relleno
    id: claveUT,
    });
  }
  //Azcapotzalco
  else if(claveUT == "02-079"){
    poligono = new google.maps.Polygon({ 
    map: map,
    paths:[
          parsear(latlng),
          //Poligono interior dibujado en dirección opuesta al poligono expetrior
          parsearIndi(obtenerpoligono("02-068").split("\n")).reverse(),
          ],
    strokeColor: "#FFFFFF",// Color de linea
    strokeOpacity: 0.5, //opacidad de la linea
    strokeWeight: 3, //grosor de la linea
    fillColor: obtenerColor(color), // Color de relleno
    fillOpacity: 0.5, // opacidad del relleno
    id: claveUT,
    });
  }
  else if(claveUT == "02-081"){
    poligono = new google.maps.Polygon({ 
    map: map,
    paths:[
          parsear(latlng),
          //Poligono interior dibujado en dirección opuesta al poligono expetrior
          parsearIndi(obtenerpoligono("02-020").split("\n")).reverse(),
          parsearIndi(obtenerpoligono("02-083").split("\n")).reverse(),
          parsearIndi(obtenerpoligono("02-012").split("\n")).reverse(),
          ],
    strokeColor: "#FFFFFF",// Color de linea
    strokeOpacity: 0.5, //opacidad de la linea
    strokeWeight: 3, //grosor de la linea
    fillColor: obtenerColor(color), // Color de relleno
    fillOpacity: 0.5, // opacidad del relleno
    id: claveUT,
    });
  }
  else if(claveUT == "02-090"){
    poligono = new google.maps.Polygon({ 
    map: map,
    paths:[
          parsear(latlng),
          //Poligono interior dibujado en dirección opuesta al poligono expetrior
          parsearIndi(obtenerpoligono("02-029").split("\n")).reverse(),
          ],
    strokeColor: "#FFFFFF",// Color de linea
    strokeOpacity: 0.5, //opacidad de la linea
    strokeWeight: 3, //grosor de la linea
    fillColor: obtenerColor(color), // Color de relleno
    fillOpacity: 0.5, // opacidad del relleno
    id: claveUT,
    });
  }
  else if(claveUT == "02-098"){
    poligono = new google.maps.Polygon({ 
    map: map,
    paths:[
          parsear(latlng),
          //Poligono interior dibujado en dirección opuesta al poligono expetrior
          parsearIndi(obtenerpoligono("02-109").split("\n")).reverse(),
          ],
    strokeColor: "#FFFFFF",// Color de linea
    strokeOpacity: 0.5, //opacidad de la linea
    strokeWeight: 3, //grosor de la linea
    fillColor: obtenerColor(color), // Color de relleno
    fillOpacity: 0.5, // opacidad del relleno
    id: claveUT,
    });
  }
  else if(claveUT == "02-080"){
    poligono = new google.maps.Polygon({ 
    map: map,
    paths:[
          parsear(latlng),
          //Poligono interior dibujado en dirección opuesta al poligono expetrior
          parsearIndi(obtenerpoligono("02-019").split("\n")).reverse(),
          ],
    strokeColor: "#FFFFFF",// Color de linea
    strokeOpacity: 0.5, //opacidad de la linea
    strokeWeight: 3, //grosor de la linea
    fillColor: obtenerColor(color), // Color de relleno
    fillOpacity: 0.5, // opacidad del relleno
    id: claveUT,
    });
  }
  else if(claveUT == "02-021"){
    poligono = new google.maps.Polygon({ 
    map: map,
    paths:[
          parsear(latlng),
          //Poligono interior dibujado en dirección opuesta al poligono expetrior
          parsearIndi(obtenerpoligono("02-055").split("\n")).reverse(),
          ],
    strokeColor: "#FFFFFF",// Color de linea
    strokeOpacity: 0.5, //opacidad de la linea
    strokeWeight: 3, //grosor de la linea
    fillColor: obtenerColor(color), // Color de relleno
    fillOpacity: 0.5, // opacidad del relleno
    id: claveUT,
    });
  }
  else if(claveUT == "02-049"){
    poligono = new google.maps.Polygon({ 
    map: map,
    paths:[
          parsear(latlng),
          //Poligono interior dibujado en dirección opuesta al poligono expetrior
          parsearIndi(obtenerpoligono("02-031").split("\n")).reverse(),
          ],
    strokeColor: "#FFFFFF",// Color de linea
    strokeOpacity: 0.5, //opacidad de la linea
    strokeWeight: 3, //grosor de la linea
    fillColor: obtenerColor(color), // Color de relleno
    fillOpacity: 0.5, // opacidad del relleno
    id: claveUT,
    });
  }
  else if(claveUT == "02-036"){
    poligono = new google.maps.Polygon({ 
    map: map,
    paths:[
          parsear(latlng),
          //Poligono interior dibujado en dirección opuesta al poligono expetrior
          parsearIndi(obtenerpoligono("02-039").split("\n")).reverse(),
          ],
    strokeColor: "#FFFFFF",// Color de linea
    strokeOpacity: 0.5, //opacidad de la linea
    strokeWeight: 3, //grosor de la linea
    fillColor: obtenerColor(color), // Color de relleno
    fillOpacity: 0.5, // opacidad del relleno
    id: claveUT,
    });
  }
  else{
    poligono = new google.maps.Polygon({ 
    map: map,
    paths: parsear(latlng),
    strokeColor: "#FFFFFF",// Color de linea
    strokeOpacity: 0.5, //opacidad de la linea
    strokeWeight: 3, //grosor de la linea
    fillColor: obtenerColor(color), // Color de relleno
    fillOpacity: 0.5, // opacidad del relleno
    id: claveUT,
    });
  }
    

    
    
    //Escucha evento de mouseover sobre poligonoUT 
  poligono.addListener('mouseover',function(event){
    this.setOptions({strokeColor: "#000000", strokeWeight: 5, fillOpacity: 0.0});
   
  });
  
  
  //Escucha evento de mouseout sobre poligonoUT
  poligono.addListener('mouseout',function(event){
    this.setOptions({strokeColor: "#FFFFFF", strokeWeight: 3, fillOpacity: 0.5});
    infoWindow.close();
  });

  
  //Infowindow que contiene el texto del Marcado 
  let infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
    //Obtenemos el texto del infoWindow
    content: contentString,
    shouldFocus: true,
    disableAutoPan: false,
  });

 infoWindow.open(poligono);
  
  // Configure the click listener.
  
  poligono.addListener("click", (mapsMouseEvent) => {
    // Close the current InfoWindow.
    infoWindow.close();
    // Create a new InfoWindow.
    infoWindow.setOptions({position: mapsMouseEvent.latLng,});
    //infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
      //position: mapsMouseEvent.latLng,
    //});
    infoWindow.open(poligono);
  });
      map.fitBounds(bounds);
        xmlhttp.open("POST", "paginas/controlador.php");
        xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
        xmlhttp.send('opcion=obtenerDatosUT&dato='+claveUT);

}

FUNCIÓN EN controlador
else if($opcion == "obtenerDatosUT"){
        
        if(isset($_POST["claveUT"])){

            $claveUT = $_POST["claveUT"];

            $query="SELECT id, entidad, claveDT, nombreDT, dttoL_2023, claveUT, nombreUT, seccC, seccP, tipoUT, poblacion, ln, color, AsText(geom) geom FROM ut_2024 WHERE claveUT = '".$claveUT."';";
            
            $response=array();
            $res=mysqli_query($conectado, $query)or die("Error de coenexión 0XEE01: " .mysqli_error($conectado));
            $cols=mysqli_fetch_array($res);

            foreach($res as $key => $value){
                $datos = array();   
                foreach($value as $v => $d){
                    $datos[$v] = $d;
                }
                array_push($response, $datos);
            }

            var_dump($response);
            // echo json_encode($response);
        }

    }    

El error que me aparece en console es este

var_dump($response)


El error que me aparece en console es este

echo json_encode($response)


La función de parsear es para las figuras mas grandes las dibuje a partir del campo geoespacial y el parsear es para las figuras dentro de las grandes
function parsear(datos){
    //Verificar como se obtiene los datos
    bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
  const poligono = [];
  var datosPoli={};

  for (var i = 0; i < coordenadas.length; i++) {
    var latlng=coordenadas[i].split(" ");
    datosPoli[i]={ lat: parseFloat(latlng[1].replace(/\s+/g, "")), lng: parseFloat(latlng[0].replace(/\s+/g, "")) };
    bounds.extend(datosPoli[i]);
    poligono.push(datosPoli[i]);  
  }
  

  return poligono;
}

function parsearIndi(coordenadas){
  //Verificar como se obtiene los datos
  //coordenadas = datos.split("\n");
  bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
  const poligono = [];
  var datosPoli={};

  for (var i = 0; i < coordenadas.length; i++) {
    var latlng=coordenadas[i].split(" ");
    datosPoli[i]={ lat: parseFloat(latlng[1].replace(/\s+/g, "")), lng: parseFloat(latlng[0].replace(/\s+/g, "")) };
    bounds.extend(datosPoli[i]);
    poligono.push(datosPoli[i]);  
  }
  

  return poligono;
}


Puedes mostrar el resultado del var_dump?

Es el que esta en la publicación @Jakala

El mensaje que pones es del echo json_encode. Yo te pregunto por la salida de $response.

No es de echo json_encode porque esta comentado

Perdona, no debo estar explicándome bien. Podrías mostrar el json que te devuelve el PHP? El error que muestras es que no se ha podido codificar el array que se genera en $response a json.

en function parsear(datos) el iterable coordenadas no existe ( aún? )

Si existe de hecho la function parsear @aloMalbarez

Por favor, puedes poner el json que has publicado en modo texto? Las imágenes son muy complicadas para copiar/pegar e intentar comprobar que está pasando. Muy probablemente este roto por las , que pone en el parámetro MULTIPOLYGON

@CarliL. por lo que leo del code, dentro de la funcion parsear(datos) la variable coordenadas, con la que intentas hacer un for, no esta declarada. probablemente sea datos.coordenadas o datos o un subset de bounds; si es una global el error puede darse por que aún no existe en el contexto

btw en la imagen lo dice mas explicito: coordenadas is not defined at parsear llamada desde dibujarUT llamada desde el readystatechange ( cuando vuelve/falla el fetch )
